# It is necessary to install a Keystone proxy in order to use the Pep proxy with Keyrock?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We are installing a Fiware enviroment in a local machine; we pretend to have an orion context broker with a Keyrock idm instance. We understand that we need to use a Pep Proxy in order to check the tokens of the requests to the orion context broker.

As we use Keyrock idm, we are wondering whether we have to install the keystone proxy or not. Is there any way to use them now without installing anything else or we are supposed to install the keystone proxy too?

This is the keystone proxy that we have found:

https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-keystone-proxy

If this is the case; How do we have to configure the pep proxy? Where do we have to put the data to connect to the Keyrock idm and where are we supposed to indicate the keystone information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have ready the new release of the Keyrock GE. With this new release Keystone Proxy will not be necessary anymore. We will publish the new documentation in a few days so please, I recommend you to use the new release.

BR

Comment: Should I use "Pep Proxy Wilma" or "Orion Pep Proxy" in order to avoid the use of keystone proxy?